# Problem with import library to send data by http

Tags: java, android, eclipse, http, intellij-idea

I'm creating android app and want to send picture by http.

I've made function to send my data and it works fine on Eclipse Android Neon 3.0, but on Intellij not (I use Intellij Idea, not Android Studio). On Eclipse with Android ADT extensions it also doesn't work. I use same JDK and SDK (try 16/19/21/22/29 API)

`import com.android.internal.http.multipart.FilePart;
import com.android.internal.http.multipart.MultipartEntity;
import com.android.internal.http.multipart.Part;
import com.android.internal.http.multipart.StringPart;`

Error (red font color) concerns last part of import (FilePart, MultipartEntity, Part, StringPart).

Only problem is that this import doesn't work (code to send file is 100% fine, works on Eclipse Android).

Comment: You probably missing the dependency for Http `MultipartEntity` .. If you are developing for Native android the you should probaly consider using a network library ,, lIke RetroFit ..

Comment: I'm not using gradle in this project. In Eclipse Android I don't need any additional library except  android-support-v4.